# What does <in TFrom, out TTo> mean?

Tags: c#, generics, covariance, contravariance

Resharper has suggested to change from

```
interface IModelMapper<TFrom, TTo>
{
    TTo Map(TFrom input);
}
```

into

```
interface IModelMapper<in TFrom, out TTo>
```

So I investigate a little and ended reading [this article](http://www.buunguyen.net/blog/new-features-of-csharp-4.html) (found through a *Wikipedia* article) and some more Google.

I am still not sure what this would imply for my application so I am tempted of not accepting the suggestion. What would are the benefits this change would introduce and I am not considering by ignoring the suggestion?

More explicitly, why should I accept it?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**Bottom Line:** Resharper has investigated your type, and discovered that `TFrom` may be used contravariantly, and `TTo` covariantly.  Accepting the refactor would allow you to use these types with greater flexibility, as described below.  If that might be of value to you, accept it.

Note, however, that accepting this refactor would **place restrictions on how you use these types in the future**.  If you ever write a method that takes `TTo` as a parameter, you'll get a compiler error, since coviariant types cannot be read in.  And ditto for `TFrom`: you'll never be able to have a method that returns this type, or has an `out` parameter of this type.

---

That's telling you that `TFrom` is contravariant, and that `TTo` is covariant.  These were features recently [added to C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devschool/archive/2010/12/15/new-features-in-c-2010-covariance-and-contravariance-and-list-lt-t-gt.aspx)

Type covariance means that a *more* specific type may be passed in, while contravariance means that a *less* specific type may be passed in.

`IEnumerable<T>` is a good example of type covariance.  Since items in an `IEnumerable<T>`  are **read only**, you may set it to something more specific:

```
IEnumerable<object> objects = new List<string>();
```

Consider what could happen *if* (hypothetically) you were allowed to do this for collections that were read/write:

```
List<object> objects = new List<string>();
objects.Add(new Car());
//runtime exception
```

To be type covariant, a generic parameter must be used in a strictly **read-only** manner; it must only ever be written **out** from the type, and never read **in** (hence the keywords).  That's why the `IEnumerable<T>` example works, but the `List<T>` example doesn't.  By the way, arrays *do* support type covariance (since Java does, I believe), and so this same kind of runtime error is possible with arrays.

Type contravariance means the opposite.  To support type contravariance a generic parameter must be read **in** only, and never written **out**.  This allows you to substitute less specific types in.

`Action<T>` is an example of type contravaince:

```
Action<object> objAction = (o => Console.WriteLine(o.ToString()));
Action<string> strAction = objAction;
strAction("Hello");
```

`strAction` is declared to take a string parameter, but it works fine if you substitute an object type.  A string will be passed in, but if the delegate it's set to work with chooses to treat it as an object, then so be it.  No harm done.

For completeness, `Func<T>` is the inverse case of `Action<T>`; here `T` is only returned, therefore it's covariant:

```
Func<string> strDelegate =  () => "Hello";
Func<object> myObjFunc = strDelegate;
object O = myObjFunc();
```

`myObjectFunc` is coded to return an object.  If you set it to something that returns a string, then, again, no harm done.

Comment: @mhttk - great.  Glad to help

Comment: Probably the best explanation of co/contravariance I've read - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As an example of how this choice might affect your application, assume you have a type `CustomerAddressMapper` that implements `IModelMapper<Customer, Address[]>` and another one `SupplierAddressMapper` that implements `IModelMapper<Supplier, Address[]>`.  The `Customer` and `Supplier` types share a base class `Company`, but their address logic is distinct, so we need separate types to handle this.

Now assume that you have a method that takes an `IMapper<Company, Address[]>`.  Before interface contravariance, you would not be able to pass instances of `CustomerAddressMapper` or `SupplierAddressMapper` to this method.  Now, if you use the `in` modifier on the `TFrom` type parameter, you can.

Furthermore, because of covariance on the `TTo` parameter, you can also pass a `CustomerAddressMapper` to methods that require an `IMapper<Customer, object>`.